# How to set all columns of dataframe as null values

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe which has n number of columns with all datatypes
I want to have a empty dataframe with same number of columns/column names
After creating the columns ; is there any way I can set the columns values to null

Comment: Dataframes are read only Datastrcutures. So whatever you ar etrygin to achive with any work around will create a new Dataframe or new columns with value as null. Are you ok with it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in following way.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName('stackoverflow')\
.getOrCreate()

sc= spark.sparkContext

df1 = sc.parallelize([
(1, 2, 3), (3,2, 4), (5,6, 7)
]).toDF(["a", "b", "c"])

df1.show()

+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
|  1|  2|  3|
|  3|  2|  4|
|  5|  6|  7|
+---+---+---+

df2 = df1.select( *[F.lit(None).alias(col)  for col in df1.columns])

df2.show()

+----+----+----+
|   a|   b|   c|
+----+----+----+
|null|null|null|
|null|null|null|
|null|null|null|
+----+----+----+
```